# Cloud function ids not responding to Telegram webhook

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, telegram-bot, telegraf

I'm trying to write my first telegram bot. I decided to use google cloud functions to execute bot logic. The code that I'm using is

```
const bot = new Telegraf(config().bot.token)
bot.start(ctx => ctx.reply('Welcome'))
bot.hears('hi', ctx => ctx.reply('Hey there'))

bot.telegram.setWebhook(
  `https://us-central1-some-project.cloudfunctions.net/${process.env.FUNCTION_TARGET}`,
);

exports.bot = https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  bot.handleUpdate(req.body, res);
})
```

The problem is that after some time of inactivity bot stops responding to messages. After redeploy of function it starts working again. I don't even know how to debug that issue.

Comment: First thing I'd suggest is to study some on GCP Cloud Logging.  From that you should be able to see the logs generated from the execution of your function and see if there are any error messages or other diagnostics produced that would give us a clue as to what the problem may be.

Comment: @Kolban looking into the logs, there are a bunch of timeouts, like this `Function execution took 60011 ms, finished with status: 'timeout'`. Is that normal ? The strange thing is that it was executing with almost zero latency for almost a day and then it suddenly started to do these timeouts

Comment: What this seems to say is that the Cloud Function is indeed being called but the function is not ending within 60 seconds and is being explicitly terminated by GCP.  Is that normal ... normally not.  I'd look into what your cloud function code is doing and why it is not responding within 60 seconds.  Is the back-end down?

Comment: Could you please provide more details, maybe what does the CF does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCF timed out because fallback needs to be defined for unsupported messages,
something like this

```
bot.on('message', ctx => ctx.reply('Not supported command'));
```